# Menu administration, how to allow special charachters

Tags: menus

I'm new to wordpress, i have created a website, for multilanguage solution i use qTranslation, my menus has also description and this is a problem, how can i allow special charcters here:

Here is link for image of my problem: http://s10.postimg.org/9l16qlt61/menu.gif

my code look so, but after saving are this charachters missing and a see content from both languages:

```
<!--:fr-->french content<!--:--><!--:it-->italian content<!--:-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of special characters do you need to put?

I never used this field in Wordpress, so I'm not sure of what I am saying, but maybe it works like in HTML, which needs you to use entity codes for letters like à, é, è, etc.

Here's a link to a list of entity code : http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/web/codehtml.html

Hope it helps...!